# Unexpected white space inside an overflowed div

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a simple attendance webapp and my problem is as follows.

http://jsfiddle.net/ssttevee/mf279tnw/

In my code above, I'm getting about 50px of white space that I can't explain or get rid of on the right of the div inside the overflow.  (Scroll all the way to the right).

I expected the overflow to stop immediately after the "Jack" column, but it continues on.

How do I get rid of that extra space?

```
.data {
  padding-left: 149px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.data .names > div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.data .names > div > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100px);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.data .row {
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.data .row > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.data .row > div:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.data .row > div .icon {
  margin-top: 7px;
}
.data .row:hover {
  background-color: rgba(66, 133, 244, 0.3);
}
.data .row:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mf279tnw/2/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spacing is due to the `width` of the inner `div`.

Please check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mf279tnw/5/

`width` removed from `.attendance-sheet .data .names > div > div`

and `border-left` added to `.attendance-sheet .data .names > div`